# How to differ languages in React Native, before component was mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was expecting something like this to work. It doesn't because *this.text.pupil* is undefined

1. Is it because of the componentWillMount?
2. If yes, how can I differ languages outside of the render() function? Because in this case I have people with different roles and the languages to render and since I am newbie to React Native it was the only "beautiful" solution I have saw.

```
...
import { t } from "../../../../methods/checkLanguage";
...

class School extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.text = t("Buildings");
  }

  people = [
    {
      name: "Max Mustermann",
      role: this.text.pupil,
      image: require("../../../../..max.jpg")
    }, ....
  ]

render() {
  return(
  .....

  {this.people.map((item, index) => (
             <ImageName key={index} name={item.name} role={item.role} image={item.image}/>
                ))}
   .....)
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining `people` as a class property? Why are you using `componentWillMount` (which is **deprecated** and has been for at least a year). Why not just call `t` in the constructor? What on Earth *is* `t` and why would you give a function a single-character name? Why would you expect an *instance variable*, that isn't even set until mount, to be defined while defining a class property? Why.... there's just too much here to pry apart what you actually want or are trying to do.

Comment: The above comment contains the correct answer.  this.text.pupil is an instance variable and it isn't set inside the class definition until the constructor is called. Perhaps you could add people = [..] to the constructor and pass pupil to the constructor as a parameter.

Comment: It's a code from the previous students I've got at my university and I should work on this app. Since I am new to React, I don't know how good the existing code is. Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: @Shamray it's bad, really, really, really bad. You would be better off working through a tutorial or five than continue working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can define and use it. Although its always better to follow some tutorial and have full understanding of the code as suggested in the comments.

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      var text = t("Buildings"); // I don't know what is t() here.
      this.state = {
        text : text,
        people : [{
            name: "Max Mustermann",
            role: text.pupil,
            image: require("../../../../..max.jpg")
          }]
      }
    }


    render() {
      const {people} = this.state
      return (
        .....

        { people.map((item, index) => (
          <ImageName key={index} name={item.name} role={item.role} image={item.image} />
        ))
    }
       .....)
    }
```